# Are there any tools available to convert game save files from the GFWL to the Steam version?

Tags: steam, games-for-windows-live

Due to the closure of the Games for Windows Live service this year, many games that previously weren't available on Steam have appeared on the service. For the game Batman: Arkham Asylum, users have found [workarounds](http://www.dayonepatch.com/index.php?/topic/94300-psa-how-to-get-your-arkham-asylumarkham-city-gfwl-saves-to-work-with-the-steamworks-version/) to make saves compatible. Therefore, I was wondering: are thise methods applicable to all GFWL games or just Batman in particular?

Answer (score 3):

Different games will require different steps to convert saves, provided it is even possible for that particular game.